# Playing a Video-DVD with scratches

Tags: dvd, vlc-media-player, scratch

Our local library has the DVD "Frozen" available, but it's badly scratched. Our DVD player at home sometimes hangs, but then skips past the scratch and continues play after about a minute or so.

My laptop is not so friendly: he just hangs and keeps on hanging. It's amazing a cheap DVD player can actually play the DVD, and the very expensive laptop can't.

**Is there a (software) way to playback the DVD "as good as possible"?** So it doesn't hang 5 minutes while insisting to play the scratched part, but just skips a minute further until it can play again? A good application, high buffers, skip-on-scratch setting? I've tried VLC but the interface is ... really advanced.

Comment: try applying toothpaste on dvd, rub it starting from center and clockwise to outside border. u can use dd tool (linux) this too can copy all the files for u from dvd to harddisk and jumps over bad sectors

Comment: Thanks botmaster. I've looked around the site for other questions regarding scratched DVDs and found these advices, but this question is (imho) sufficiently different: it's not about files, but a video-DVD, and it's a rental DVD so I'd prefer not to mess with it too much. Rubbing on toothpaste (hardware fix) would really be my very last resort, I'd prefer a software option if possible. Skipping is allowed, hanging is to be avoided.

Comment: we use dd to take an image of storage device which even works in very bad damages for forensics. u can try take an image from it to your harddisk and watch it there

Comment: Sometimes using a bit of baby oil on the scratches will allow it to read better (wipe off excess oil)